# Why use bind and unbind events to an elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a question about the binding and unbinding events to elements in JavaScript. I understand this: we bind and unbind elements to a elements when we create an element and this do something so we bind an event and when the user delete this element with and action the event listener needs to be remove because the element was removed, this is was I think, so my question is I am correct? Or when and why we bind and unbind events.

Comment: Unclear exactly what your question is. The idea of binding an event to an element is to get that element to do something when a certain circumstance is met. When you no longer want it to do that thing anymore, you unbind a function for that event on that element.

Comment: when element is removed...so are any bound event listeners. You unbind for different reasons to do with business logic. Question is really too broad as a result of that reasoning

Comment: I'm early in javascript, so I was confuse in when bind an event and when this be deleted there is a need to unbind manually the event attached to this element, but now I have clear that bind an event to a element when you need to this do something in certain circumstances and unbind when this not need more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons of when and why to bind an event are too numerous to list here (probably the former is more broad than the latter).

However, 'we' as programmers use functions such as `bind()` so that our code may listen to events that occur on a particular element.

`unbind()` is used when we no longer need to receive callbacks that an element has received such an event.

As to *when* we use `bind()` and `unbind()` depends entirely upon the project and requirements for the event. Sometimes the events will be bound upon the creation of an element. Sometimes they'll be bound by a trigger (such as a user clicking a widget, for example), and sometimes they will be bound by the response of an AJAX call (or similar server-side callback). Similarly, we may use `unbind()` inside of a callback from another event, or when something happens on the server.

As you can see, there is no "definitive" answer to when we use `bind()` and `unbind()`. However, you're slightly incorrect in your statement that `unbind()` is used when an element is removed. That is not necessary, when the element is removed, its event bindings are automatically discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have this span:

```
<span id="my-span">Hello.</span>
```

I want to be notified when a click occurs:

```
var span = document.getElementById('my-span');
var alertWhenMySpanIsClicked = function () {
    alert('my span was clicked');
};
span.addEventListener(
    'click', alertWhenMySpanIsClicked
);
```

I don't want to be notified anymore:

```
span.removeEventListener(
    'click', alertWhenMySpanIsClicked
);
```